# Trying to Send Email Alert on Contact with Multiple Accounts

Tags: visual-flows

I created a flow where it will do the count of accounts. The purpose is to get the flow to be invoked once the 2nd account is created. However, when I create an account/contact under the contact, the number is not updating under the Number Dataype.

I tried to reverse engineer what I saw in the article( https://www.xgeek.net/salesforce/create-roll-up-summary-field-to-count-contacts-on-account-with-process-builder-and-flows/) for my purpose, where did I go wrong? The Account/Contact is a fairly new object, and I am wondering if I should do the roll-up from the flow directly on the Lead instead of the Related Object.

[image: Flow]

[image: ValidateAccount]
[image: SearchContacts]
[image: AssignValues]
[image: LoopContacts]